# Show custom dialog in for loop

Tags: android, for-loop, dialog, sleep

I want to show custom dialogs in order. Each dialog must shown for 5 second then it must be dismissed and the other one must be shown. I use for loop and my code looks like:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
        popupView.show();
        SystemClock.sleep(3000);
        popupView.dismiss();
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: dialogs are asynchronous

Comment: I dont want show multiple dialogs at the same time I want to show in order

Comment: Your code shows the same Dialog 10 times.

Comment: Yes I want to do that if I can do that I can change the content of dialog but it gives an error and no dialog is shown

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and adjust the time interval as your need.

```
showDialogs();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doShowDialog = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    if (mDialogCounter < 5) {
                        showDialogs();
                        mDialogCounter++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doShowDialog, 5000, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply its working but i want to 2 second delay between dismiss and show how can i do this?

Comment: Put the code line to show dialog inside dialog dismiss listener by applying the same logic to delay the action.